# View with small modifications for different types of article

Tags: database, forms, view, yii

I have one view for a type of article, I need to extends this view and if user open article type "Special" I need to show some new fields in this view.

I don't want to create a separate view for this type of form because differs only one field.

Also I need to save in database, in field "type" one different value if "Special" article is saved.

Please suggest me how I can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by adding a public variable in Article model, in controller I set the variable with one string, and on view I verify this string.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should simply use a if statement in your view to display, or not, additional fields, and use [`beforeSave`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#beforeSave-detail) method in your model to handle your type attribute.

```
protected function beforeSave()
{
    // if ('Special' article)
    //     $this->type = 'value';
    parent::beforeSave();
}
```

You should also consider using [scenario](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/266/understanding-scenarios/).

Comment: I have a form for standart article, i need to verify if is accessed link for Special article to display some fields. I don't know how I can verify this.